# Arduino Uno 3.3V pin to GND short how to fix

Tags: arduino-uno

Hi I am new to the Arduino world. I was playing around with my Arduino UNO making LEDs go on and off in a sequence. Then I connected a motor to the N.0 pins but found it doesn't work so I plugged it doesn't work so I plugged it in 3.3V pin and it worked. I tried to reverse the connections but the one cable slipped and it connected to the metal shielding of the motor now it is not working when plugging it in USB it. Power LED just flashes red and turns off emediatly. Reset button doesn't seem to do annything. Is there a possible fix for this.[image]

Comment: There is, but it would probably cost you more than the cost of a new counterfeit Uno from AliExpress.

Comment: First you need to identify what component is what, and then work out which has been destroyed by your short circuit (probably the 3.3V regulator, whichever component that is). Then identify the component make and model, and buy a new one. Then replace it and hope. Since that is not an official Arduino UNO you are probably going to have problems identifying the components and their model numbers in order to get a replacement. Just ditch it and get a new one.

Comment: @Majenko I believe it is a "clone" and not a "counterfeit". A "counterfeit" would have the Arduino logo and would be sold as an "original" with fake box etc.

Comment: Tomaytos, tomahtos. It's a piece of cheap Chinese crap either way.

Comment: It was working fine so I really don't care about quality I just need a processing board for my project besides I am a begginer and not really worth it to invest in high quality expensive equipment I will break so thanks for suggesting AliExpress but is it trust worthy.